# Sorting by either multiple or single criteria failing

Tags: javascript

I have the following example data that I'm trying to sort by multiple criteria:

1. `details.length` (from smaller to bigger)
2. `details.type` (alphabetically : Claimant, FellowPassenger)

If I sort it by `details.length` it seems to work but `details.type` doesn't both on multiple or single sorting criteria versions as data isn't sorted alphabetically (`Claimant` should appear first than `Fellow`).

So the output should be:

```
 sortedByMultiple:  [
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020672_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Claimant",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "rejected"
  },
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020890_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "rejected"
  },
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020600_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Claimant",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      },
      {
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "accepted"
  }
]
```

```js
const groupedStackOverflow = [
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020600_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Last Name"
      },
      {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Claimant",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "accepted"
  },
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020890_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Last Name"
      }
  ],
    "state": "rejected"
  },
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020672_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
    {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Claimant",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "rejected"
  }
]

console.log("groupedStackOverflow: ",groupedStackOverflow )


const sortedByMultiple = groupedStackOverflow.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.details.length - b.details.length || a.details.type - b.details.type ;
});

console.log("sortedByMultiple: ", sortedByMultiple);


const sortedByOne = groupedStackOverflow.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.details.type - b.details.type ;
});

console.log("sortedByOne: ", sortedByOne);
```

Comment: You said 'FellowPassenger' - I assume you meant just 'Fellow'? So you want to sort the outer objects by the length of the details array, and then sort each details array only by the 'type' of each object in the array? And do the fellow passengers need to be sorted by name?

Comment: @AndrewParks yes, I meant Fellow instead. Corrected. No, just length + type, no need to order by name, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your sort condition using a string comparison because `a.details.type - b.details.type` returns `NaN`.

Try this:

```js
const groupedStackOverflow = [
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020600_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Last Name"
      },
      {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Claimant",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "accepted"
  },
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020600_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Last Name"
      },
      {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Dummy",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "accepted"
  },
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020890_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Last Name"
      }
  ],
    "state": "rejected"
  },
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020672_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [
    {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Claimant",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "rejected"
  }
]

console.log("groupedStackOverflow: ",groupedStackOverflow )

const stringComparison = function (a,b) {
  return a.type.localeCompare(b.type);
}
const sortedByMultiple = groupedStackOverflow.sort(function (a, b) {
      if(a.details.length > 1)  a.details.sort(stringComparison);
      if(b.details.length > 1)  b.details.sort(stringComparison);
      return a.details.length - b.details.length || stringComparison(a.details[0],b.details[0]);
});

console.log("sortedByMultiple: ", sortedByMultiple);
```

You were also accessing `type` in the wrong way, `details` is an array and that's why it gives you an error. You can now modify that snippet to adjust it based on your needs

Comment: thank you but would you care to elaborate? I'm not familiar with it, tried to use `a.details.type.charCodeAt()-b.details.type.charCodeAt()` and `details.type.charCodeAt()` and just get errors

Comment: I edited my answers, if u need more just ask me, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, We have sorted the array based on the details object length.
- After that, we compared object details.type with the help of `String.prototype.localeCompare()` method for sorting the types.

```js
const groupedStackOverflow = [{
    "document_file_name": "4020600_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [{
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Last Name"
      },
      {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Claimant",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "accepted"
  },
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020890_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [{
      "id": 10000,
      "type": "Fellow",
      "name": "Fellow First Name Last Name"
    }],
    "state": "rejected"
  },
  {
    "document_file_name": "4020672_FileName.pdf",
    "details": [{
      "id": 20656,
      "type": "Claimant",
      "name": "First Name Last Name"
    }],
    "state": "rejected"
  }
]


// sorting based upon index
const sortedByLength = groupedStackOverflow.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.details.length - b.details.length;
});
// sorting based upon details type alphbatically
const finalSorted = groupedStackOverflow.map(item => {
  if (item.details.length > 1) {
    return item.details.sort((a, b) => {
      // we are using localeCompare() method to sort details.type
      return (a.type).localeCompare(b.type);
    });
  } else {
    return item;
  }
})
console.log(finalSorted);
```

Comment: thank you for your help. A couple of remarks: what's the point of the 1st filter if you're always maping based on `groupedStackOverflow`? Also, you're just ordering with `localCompare` if the length > 1, while it should always order by that.